# How to give size of a structure array member in c at runtime

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, struct, structure

I have a structure which looks like -

```
struct stack{
 int top;
 char string[size][80];
}stackV;
```

I want to give user an option to allocate size of char string array at runtime.
I had used scanf function to do this -

I tried to achive it by doing -

```
int size=0;
 struct stack{
  int top;
  char string[size][80];
 } stackV;
```

But by doing this i got warning which says - variably modified 'string' at file scope

Is there any way by which we can assign size to a structure member array .
I can't create a structure inside any function because the structure member is used by other functions also.

Comment: Look for "flexible array member".

Comment: If your using a stack data structure, you should try using dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: You can use `malloc`.

Comment: @Swanand I tried doing it like this- 
int *size;
size = (int*)malloc(1*sizeof(int));

struct stack{
   int top;
   char string[*size][80];
}stackV;                                                                                                     But i am getting warning message which says Multiple markers at this line and other warning says invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')

Comment: @SwetaSingh You should use malloc to allocate memory of user-entered size to `string`.

Comment: @Swanand I tried using malloc but i am getting warnings. Could you please guide or tell me how to do it correctly. I just started learning c

Answer (score 2):

You can use a *flexible array member* to achieve what you need:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct 
{
   int top;
   char string[][80];
} stackv;

int main() 
{
  size_t strings = 3;

  stackv* s = malloc(sizeof(stackv) + strings*80);
  strcpy(s->string[0], "test");
  strcpy(s->string[1], "hello");
  strcpy(s->string[2], "world");

  for(size_t i=0; i<strings; i++)
  {
    puts(s->string[i]);
  }

  free(s);
  return 0;
}
```

The declaration of `char string[][80];` tells the compiler that there will be an unknown amount of `char [80]` arrays at the end of the struct.

The `sizeof(stackv)` will therefore only give the size of all other members except the last one (in this case an integer).

Answer (score 0):

You don't know how many elements will be in your stack.
Only the user gives you the "size" in the runtime; so you can't allocate an array statically (compilation time), but allocate it dynamically (run time) when getting the size from the user.
You are getting an "warning" because you define "size" from size "0" then you try to declare an array of this size and according to the spec there is no array of size 0 as I understand):

```
ISO 9899:2011 6.7.6.2:

    If the expression is a constant expression, it shall have a value greater than zero.
```

How to allocate the array dynamically as a struct which contains "size" elements and each element is a string of 80 chars?

```
#define STR_LEN 80
struct stack {
   int top;
   char *string;
} stackv;

enum {
    SUCCESS = 0,
    FAILURE,
};

int InitStack(stackv *stackv, int size) {
    if (size <= 0)
        return FAILURE;

    stackv->string = (char *)malloc(size*sizeof(char)*80);
    if (stackv->string == NULL)
        return FAILURE;

    stackv->top = 0;

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

In the main function, you declare the variable "stackv" and pass it by reference (pointer) to the initialization function which I wrote.

Comment: I am getting Field 'string' could not be resolved and Field 'top' could not be resolved warning

Comment: It is true that zero-sized arrays are not allowed (including VLAs), but the actual reason for the warning is that you can't declare a VLA with static storage duration - that doesn't make any sense. If you wanted to do that, you'd use a plain array.

Answer (score -2):

This code compiles correctly for me:

```
int size = 10;

typedef struct 
{
   int top;
   char string[size][80];
} stackv;
```

I'm using:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 5.4.1-3) 5.4.1 20161019
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: Because you didn't put it at file scope, obviously. This doesn't answer the question.